# Why isn't work when trying subtraction in postfix evaluation?

Tags: c++, expression, expression-evaluation

I'm trying to getting result from postfix. But it gives me wrong when subtraction, and don't know why. Please give many helps for c++ newbie.

I got two operands from stack. And tried subtraction "last popped" - "first popped".

```
/*pf_exp is postfix expression. String type*/
for (int i=0; i<pf_exp.length(); i++)
{
    int sub_result; // saving result.
    if (48 <= (int)pf_exp[i] && (int)pf_exp[i] <= 57)
    {
        operands.push((int)pf_exp[i] - 48);
    }
    else
    {
        /*operators is a stack<int> from '#include<stack>' storing operands.*/
        int operand2 = operands.top();
        operands.pop();
        int operand1 = operands.top();
        operands.pop();
        if(pf_exp[i] == '+')
        {
            sub_result = operand1 + operand2;
        }
        else if(pf_exp[i] == '-')
        {
            sub_result = operand1 - operand2;
        }
        else if(pf_exp[i] == '*')
        {
            sub_result = operand1 * operand2;
        }
        else if(pf_exp[i] == '/')
        {
            sub_result = operand1 / operand2;
        }
        operands.push(sub_result);
    }
}
```

I expect the output of "789--" to be "-10" but the actual output is "8".

Comment: Why do you expect `-10` from `(7 - (8 - 9))`?

Comment: The operands for - and / come off the stack in the 'wrong' order. You have to compensate for that.

Comment: @BenVoigt Isn't ```789--``` means ```7-8-9```? Am I thinking wrong about changing infix to postfix?

Comment: No, to write `(7-8)-9` in RPN is `78-9-`

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh god... I was a fool....

Comment: @user207421 Really? Should my code change ```operand1 -(or /) operand2``` to ```operand2 -(or /) operand1```?

Comment: Actually I should (because RPN allows multidigit numbers) say that in RPN it is `7↓8-9-` where ↓ indicates the "push" operation

Comment: @JWLee: You've already handled the order by popping `operand2` before `operand1`, that part is already correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt OK! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the stack as a queue. You expect (7 - 8) - 9 = -10, but, since you are using a stack, the items added last are returned, so as Ben wrote, you are actually doing 7 - (8 - 9) = 8. Use a queue instead, and change the order of the operands to get what you actually wanted.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my explanation did not take the postfix evaluation into account. As the comment states, it should always use a stack by definition. Nonetheless, my answer probably explains, why you were thinking of the wrong result.

Comment: Postfix evaluation requires a stack, not a queue.

Comment: I thought ```789--``` means ```7-8-9```. Am I thinking wrong about changing from infix to postfix?

Comment: @JWLee: You must be thinking about it wrong, but it isn't that complicated.  Step 1: Write canonical infix making all parentheses explicit: `(7-8)-9` Step 2: Move each operator to postfix position: `(78-)9-`.  Step 3: Remove parentheses: `78-9-`

Comment: Note that the *reason* that postfix notation is defined to require a stack, is that with a queue you would always perform operations from left to right: `7↓8-9-` and `7↓8↓9--` are evaluated the same.  With the stack, you can implement any precedence of operations, making it possible to evaluate expressions like `(a+b)/(c-d)` which simply would be impossible with a queue (with the stack, enter `a↓b+c↓d-/`).